# TextView is not programmatically added to my Layout

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to add TextViews to LinearLayout programmatically. The amount of TextViews is based on UserInput which he can type in using AlertDialog Builder
But the TextViews are not added to the Layout. I don't know why. Here is my whole code. What is wrong in my code?

```
public class HandleTableClick extends AppCompatActivity {
public int personsnumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.handle_table_click);
    final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Type number of persons");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
    String persons = input.getText().toString();
    try {
        personsnumber = Integer.parseInt(persons);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){

    }
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            TextView[] pairs=new TextView[personsnumber];
            for(int l=0; l<personsnumber; l++)
            {
                pairs[l] = new TextView(HandleTableClick.this);
                pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
                pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
                pairs[l].setId(l);
                pairs[l].setText((l + 1) + ": something");
                myLayout.addView(pairs[l]);
            }
        }
    });

    alert.show();


}
}
```

Comment: Did you debug at all? Specifically, did you check the value of `personsnumber` in `onClick()`?

Comment: Yes, but I think personsnumber is still 0 (zero) . But could not figure out why.

Comment: I think a possible reason could be because your `EditText` has the `final` keyword. Try taking that out. Also try doing `EditText input = findViewById(R.id.editText);`.

Comment: Look at when you're getting that value from the `EditText` – before the `AlertDialog` is even shown. You need to get that value in `onClick()`. (Btw, that's the kind of info you want to include in your question.)

Comment: The editText input is created programmatically. I can't use findViewById here.

Comment: @MikeM. could you specifiy your answer please, I did not get it.

Comment: You don't need `findViewById()`. You already have a reference to the `EditText`. Move the `String persons = input.getText().toString();` and parsing section to inside `onClick()`.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I already tested it! and function perfect! :)
  And I added the setWeightSum to distribute the textView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView textView;
        Integer personsnumber;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            personsnumber=0;
            final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Type number of persons");
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String persons = input.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        personsnumber = Integer.parseInt(persons);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                    }
                    myLayout.setWeightSum(personsnumber);
                    for(int l=0; l<personsnumber; l++)
                    {
                        textView= new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        textView.setTextSize(15);
                        textView.setId(l);
                        textView.setText((l + 1) + ": something");
                        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        myLayout.addView(textView);

                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }


        }
```